# jQuery - Get element from array as jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, word-wrap

If I call

```
$(".myClass")
```

I get an array of elements. If I now want to get the first element as jquery element I would do something like this:

```
$($(".myClass").get(0))
```

So I wrap the DOM-Element, which I get from the array again with the jQuery operator. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Some get method, which returns a jQuery element for example?

Comment: Check here http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Use `$(".myClass").eq(0)` for the equivalent, without having to re-wrap in jQuery

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use the [`eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(".myClass").eq(0)
```

This returns a jQuery object, whereas `.get()` returns a DOM element.

`.eq()` lets you specify the index, but if you just want the first you can use `.first()`, or if you just want the last you can use (surprise!) `.last()`.

> *"I get an array of elements."*

No you don't, you get a jQuery object which is an array-like object, not an actual array.

If you plan to use jQuery much I suggest spending half an hour browsing through the [list of all methods](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Or use the each method to traverse.

```js
$(".myClass").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html())
})
```